# Writing a syntax analyser (parser) from BNF without using a generator

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree, bnf

I'm interested in writing a parser (syntax analyser) from a BNF grammar without using a generator tool like yacc or bison.

I take as example the BNF for simple arithmetic expression : (extracted from the Dragon Book 2.2.6)

```
expr -> expr + term | expire - term | term
term -> term * factor | term / factor | factor
factor -> number | (expr)
```

Suppose I would like to create the equivalent code.

I guess I should create three functions called `parseExpr`, `parseTerm` and `parseFactor`.

How do I construct these functions regarding to the BNF defined upwards ?

For the `parseFactor` it seems to be obvious :

1. Get the token type
2. If type number return a node for number type
3. If the token represents an opening parenthesis, get the node returned by `parseExpr`
4. Check that next token is a closing parenthesis. If yes, return the node obtained at 3. If no, throw an error

For the `parseExpr`, I'm a little bit confused about how to start and interpret the production : `expr -> expr + term | expire - term | term`

How to translate this production ? How to detect which case applies ? Same question for the last production ?

Comment: Could you supply a sample input and output for these functions?

Comment: See this SO answer for how to manually code a recursive descent parser directly from a grammar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245962/is-there-an-alternative-for-flex-bison-that-is-usable-on-8-bit-embedded-systems/2336769#2336769

Comment: This link sounds really good :) Could you add explanation about it : why should we remove left recursion and how do you do it ?

Comment: You can take a look at [libmarpa](https://github.com/jeffreykegler/libmarpa) which implements the [Marpa parsing algorithm](http://savage.net.au/Marpa.html), is not a parser generator, you need to create the grammar and write a lexer.